no puedo resolver el siguinte error ¿No se puede resolver el símbolo sqliteDatabase?
Estoy haciendo una base de datos con SQLite con Java, pero me aparece un error de símbolo, cabe mencionar que uso Android Studio Koala, que es la version 2024, también que me estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programacion.
package com.example.myapplication.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NOMBRE = "restaurant.db";
    public static final String TABLE_RESTAURANTS = "t_restaurants";

    public DbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NOMBRE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        sqliteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_RESTAURANTS + "(" +
                " id INTERGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                "nombre TEXT NOT NULL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}


Tienes un error en la primera línea del método public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {, si observas, el parámetro se llama db, pero tú estás usando sqliteDatabase, debes cambiar esa primera línea usando db, algo así: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  ... RESTO DE LA CONSULTA AQUÍ"); Una recomendación, si estás empezando, en vez de usar esta herramienta, considera usar la Biblioteca de persistencias Room. SQLiteOpenHelper es prehistórica con respecto a Room.
